# Win10 IoT +Raspberry PI 2 official touch display support

Tags: touchscreen, windows-iot

I'm looking to have the new 7" Raspberry official touch screen working on Windows 10 IoT.

Does anyone have ever tried it? It looks to work pretty well with LINUX but there is no such docs or samples on get it working on Win10 IoT.

Thanks

Comment: People on raspberry or microsoft can reply on whether a driver is around or with some workaround in order to get it working or someone from driver development maybe had tried something but it still a development question IMHO...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

the touchscreen made by the Raspberry Pi Foundation is not yet fully supported by Windows 10 IoT Core 10586. The display works but not the touch.

https://www.raspberrypi.org/products/raspberry-pi-touch-display/

As an alternative, you might use this

https://www.hackster.io/weiqing/unique-way-to-add-touch-on-raspberrypi2-running-windows-iot-bf02e0

Comment: Hey @Danvy,

Looks like we have to wait... Sad :(

We have some production scenario for both card payment scenarios and also car infotainment devices but both requires touch interfaces since both are headed devices...

This is pretty basic and we should have it working at least on supported devices like PI2.

Thanks anyway for the reply.

Comment: @danvy, you say "The display works", how do you back up that statement? A post you read or have you gotten it to work?

Comment: Some internal tests

Comment: Thanks for the reply @danvy, would be nice to have it working... Many scenarios for IoT requires a touch interface and PI2 is one of the most used hardwares for development nowadays. The supported touch here http://ms-iot.github.io/content/en-US/win10/SupportedInterfaces.htm is never on stock while PI Foundation one is widely accessible. I believe it is a matter of having drivers for the touch controller. Thanks

Comment: The screen is now supported on the Insider Preview build

Answer (score 2):

The screen now seems to be fully supported on the latest Insider Preview build (14342).

Answer (score 0):

I use this https://www.adafruit.com/products/2407 screen and everything works (Touch / Display) fine

Comment: could you please describe how you got it working? The product description mention "We also noted it does not work with a Raspberry Pi + Windows 10 IOT yet.". Are you sure it worked on Windowd 10 *IoT*? Also, looks like it emulates a mouse and not a touch device...

Comment: Hi - you install / setup it following this blog post http://blog.falafel.com/setting-up-a-7-inch-touchscreen-on-a-pi-2-with-windows-iot-core-insider-preview/ -- you are right - it act's as a mouse - so you can use "normal" UI elements but zoom or other actions (multi touch) are not possible

Comment: I see. Thanks! This unit actually has a problem for our project due to the connectors which are on the left side. But thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The display is not supported by Windows 10 IoT (using Version 10.0.10586.0) yet. Microsoft needs to work on the drivers, because this display is already in use by Raspberry users.

To get around this limitation you can get an [Adafruit TFP401 HDMI/DVI Decoder with Touch](https://www.adafruit.com/product/2219) and connect the display with the HDMI and USB inputs of the Raspberry. See [Setting up a 7-inch Touchscreen on a Pi 2 with Windows IoT Core Insider Preview](http://blog.falafel.com/setting-up-a-7-inch-touchscreen-on-a-pi-2-with-windows-iot-core-insider-preview/) by Carey Payette for detailed instructions.

Comment: yes, drivers are needed. This Adafruit is not a true touch device. It is a "mouse simulator". Gestures are not supported...