# Official 7 inch display with Windows 10 preview?

Tags: windows-iot

I found this answer https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/50118/894 which says it works with the older preview version referenced. I have installed the latest preview and when I turn it on, I get white and pink lines.

Do I need the older release to get it to work? If so, where can I find it?

I don't even care about the touch screen for now, I just want to use the Raspberry 3 in the display case and screen I have.

Comment: The screen display should work fine. It looks like it worked for a while it was just touch capabilities added recently. Are you sure the cable is inserted properly? And the correct way around?

Comment: Travis did you manage to work out the problem you were having?

Comment: sorry no, i will update this thread (new to posting here)

Comment: I abandoned this project, used the screen to create a retro-pie stand alone. I will try the updated drivers next time.

Comment: OK - Thanks Travis. I suppose we can leave this question open until somebody works out how to make it work or until the driver gets updates? Thanks for replying.